# Are domestic rats allowed as pets in Islam?

Tags: pets

One of my friends have been keeping domestic rats and me and her are wondering if it’s haram to do so,she has about 5 and said I should get one,but when I searched if it’s permissible to keep rats I couldn’t find a clear answer saying yes or no

Comment: Keeping them as pets seems rather contrary to the hadith that call them  فواسق and command killing them, [here](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/120) and [here](http://sunnah.com/muslim/15/76) etc.